# Simple question - How $x^4 +y^4 -2(x-y)^2$ having a minimum at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I know this is a silly question, but I need to prove that

$$ f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 -2 (x-y)^2 $$

is having a minima at $(0,0)$.

I tried doing maxima and minima method to it but the determinant i.e $AC- B^2= 0 $

So, we need to prove it algebraically only.

Comment: Which determinant?

Comment: @Bernard I think he is referring to the determinant for the multivariate second derivative test where $A=f_{xx},B=f_{xy},C=f_{yy}$ such that $\Delta=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2 $ is the determinant

Comment: In the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ there will be values $f(x,y)$ both greater than and less than $0.$  e.g. $f(0,0) = 0, f(0.1,-0.1) < 0-, f(0.1,0.1) >  0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_x = 4x^3 - 4x +4y = 0, f_y = 4y^3 - 4y + 4x = 0\implies 4(x^3+y^3) = 0 \implies x = -y$ or $x^2 - xy + y^2 = 0$ which yields $x = y = 0$. If $x = -y \implies 4x^3 - 8x = 0 \implies 4x(x^2 - 2) = 0\implies x = 0, \pm \sqrt{2}\implies y = 0,\mp \sqrt{2}$. Next $f_{xx}= 12x^2 - 4$. Thus $f_{xx}(\pm \sqrt{2}) = 20 > 0$. So by the second derivative test ( see a calculus book for this test ) the min are at these points. Thus $f_{\text{min}} = f(\pm \sqrt{2}, \mp \sqrt{2})= -8 $ since $f(0,0) = 0 > -8$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the doubt .

Comment: $(\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ are minimum points the  $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$ ones are not.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is not at $(0,0)$. For example, $f(x,0)=x^4-2x^2$ achieves its minimum (i.e. $-1$) when $x^2=1$.

Comment: And furthermore, it's not even a local minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\sqrt2$ and $y=-\sqrt2$ then we get a value $-8$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2\geq-8$$ or
$$x^4+y^4+8-2(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
Now, by AM-GM $$x^4+y^4+8\geq2\sqrt{8(x^4+y^4)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$2\sqrt{8(x^4+y^4)}\geq2(x-y)^2$$ or
$$8(x^4+y^4)\geq(x-y)^4$$ or
$$8((x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2)\geq(x^2+y^2-2xy)^2$$ or
$$7(x^2+y^2)^2+4(x^2+y^2)xy-20x^2y^2\geq0$$ or $$7(x^2+y^2)^2+14(x^2+y^2)xy-10(x^2+y^2)xy-20x^2y^2\geq0$$ or
$$7(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2+2xy)-10xy(x^2+y^2+2xy)\geq0$$ or
$$(x+y)^2(7x^2-10xy+7y^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Could you please explain in more details the 2 last lines? Thanks!

Comment: @Ibra It was typo. I fixed. Thank you! The inequality $8(x^4+y^4)\geq(x-y)^4$ follows also from Jensen for $f(x)=x^4$: $\frac{x^4+(-y)^4}{2}\geq\left(\frac{x+(-y)}{2}\right)^4$.

Comment: Thank you. I still struggle with last line...

Comment: @Ibra I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

$x = u+v\\y = u-v$

$f(u,v) = 2u^4 + 12u^2v^2 + 2v^4 - 4v^2$

$f(u,0) =  2u^4$ has a minimum at $(0,0)$

$f(0,v) =  2v^4 - 4v^2$ has a local maximum at $(0,v)$

$f(0,0)$ has a saddle at $(0,0)$