# Lower bound of $x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds

Let's consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2$.

I want to show that it is bounded below.

---

First, I manipulated $f$ as follows:
$$
x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2=x^4-2x^2+y^4-2y^2+4xy+x^2-x^2+4y^2-4y^2=\\
x^4-3x^2+y^4-6y^2+(x+2y)^2=x^2(x^2-3)+y^2(y^2-6)+(x+2y)^2.
$$
If $f$ had no lower bound then there must exist a sequence $(x_k,y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(x_k,y_k)=-\infty$. The limit of $(x_k,y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ must attain one of the following four values:

$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(-\infty,+\infty)$,$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(+\infty,-\infty)$,$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(c,-\infty)$,$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(-\infty,c)$,

where $c\in\mathbb{R}$. In fact, if $(x_k,y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ had a finite limit, e.g. $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(c,d)$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ then by continuity $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(x_k,y_k)$ would be finite which we had ruled out.

However, we see that in each of the four cases $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(x_k,y_k)=\infty$. So $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}f(x_k,y_k)=-\infty$ is impossible which shows that $f$ is bounded below.

---

Is this correct?
Do you have a quicker or more elegant approach? This seems very complicated.

Comment: Note $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2)^2\ge0$.

Comment: Never have I seen such a complex approach to such a simple problem

Comment: Should your function $f$ be $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2\color{red}{(x-y)}^2$? You seem to assume this on your attempt.

Comment: I completely disagree all the downvotes. I am aware almost everyone in the world can observe this is a perfect square.  But, if you don't like the OP's attempts, then don't upvote. This question is not a PSQ and the question contains enough context and does not contradict any of the rules of the MSE. +1

Comment: @MartinR I am sorry it was a stupid typo. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Philipp: I have retracted my closing vote. However, your “manipulation of $f$” is still wrong.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2396142/42969.

Comment: @MartinR, where exactly is it wrong?

Comment: @Philipp: The LHS has the term $4xy$ and the RHS $2xy$.

Comment: Do not modify a question after answers have appeared.

Comment: @MartinR, ah ok I see, thanks. I have edited it. However, this doesn't affect much the idea I had.

Comment: $(x_k, y_k)$ having no finite limit does not imply that one of those four cases must occur.

Comment: If $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $y=-\sqrt{2}$ then what is the value of $f(\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ and what can you ay about this value?

Comment: @MartinR, my statement was, if $f$ has no lower bound then there must occur one of the four cases. Why is that wrong?

Comment: @Philipp: As an example, $(x_k, y_k)$ could “diverge to infinity” in a spiral.

Comment: @MartinR, I am not sure what you mean by "in a spiral" but in your answer you said that $\Vert(x_k,y_k)\Vert= \sqrt{x_k^2+y_k^2}\to\infty$ and this shows that either $x_k$ or $y_k$ must go to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Philipp: Example: $(x_k, y_k) = (k \cos(k), k \sin(k))$. Neither $x_k$ nor $y_k$ converge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, both are positive and negative infinitely often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that if $f$ is not bounded below then $f(x_k, y_k) \to -\infty$ for some sequence $(x_k, y_k)$, and that sequence can not have a finite limit point. However, that does not imply that one of the four cases

- $\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(-\infty,+\infty)$,
- $\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(+\infty,-\infty)$,
- $\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(c,-\infty)$,
- $\lim_{k\to\infty}(x_k,y_k)=(-\infty,c)$

must occur. You can only conclude that $\Vert (x_k, y_k) \Vert = \sqrt{x_k^2 + y_k^2} \to \infty$ (which implies $|x_k| \to \infty$ or $|y_k| \to \infty$, or both).

But your representation of $f$ as
$$
 f(x, y) = x^2(x^2-3)+y^2(y^2-6)+(x+2y)^2
$$
can be used as a starting point for a proof, you only have to show that all three terms on the right-hand side are bounded below. The last term is non-negative, and the first two terms are monic polynomials in a single variable of even degree, and therefore bounded below.

*Side note:* a more symmetric representation is
$$
f(x, y) = x^2(x^2-4)+y^2(y^2-4)+2(x+y)^2 \\
 = (x^2-2)^2 + (y^2-2)^2 +2(x+y)^2 -8
$$
which leads to the sharp lower bound $f(x, y) \ge -8$. Equality holds if $x^2=y^2=2$ and $x=-y$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert for check your analysis. Therefore, I just want to deal with the algebraic part.

---

Your function is given as follows:

$$f(x,y):=x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2$$

If you take $x=a+b,~ y=a-b$, then we have

$$\begin{align}g(a,b):&=2a^4 + 12 a^2 b^2 + 2 b^4 - 8 b^2\\
&=2a^2(a^2+6b^2)+2b^4-8b^2\\
&=2a^2(a^2+6b^2)+2\left(b^2-2\right)^2-8\\
&≥-8\end{align}$$

We conclude that,

$$\min \left\{g(a,b)\right\}=-8\\
\text{at}~a=0,~b=\pm\sqrt 2$$

This means,

$$\min\left\{f(x,y)\right\}=-8\\
\text{at}~x=\pm\sqrt 2,~y=\mp\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: (+1) Very clever $a\pm b$ substitution.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thank you for reviewing my attempts.